# VBA is only saving every second open PowerPoint presentation

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I have 31 graphs in an Excel file which need to be exported to their own individual PowerPoint file and the subsequent 31 PowerPoint presentations should then be saved.

Running the below code, all graphs are successfully exported to individual presentations; however, only every second presentation (PowerPoint1, PowerPoint3, PowerPoint5 etc.) is saved as a file down my machine. Any idea why?

Note: the 'path' variable was defined earlier in the code when the user was given the option to select their own path.

Any guidance is appreciated.

```
Const ppLayoutBlank = 2
Const ppViewSlide = 1
Const ppFixedFormatTypePDF As Long = 2
Const ppPrintSelection As Long = 2
Option Explicit

Sub ExportChartstoPowerPoint()

'
' Code to allow user to choose path goes here
'

Dim chr
For Each chr In Sheets("My Excel File").ChartObjects
    Dim PPApp As Object
    Set PPApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
    PPApp.Presentations.Add
    PPApp.ActiveWindow.ViewType = ppViewSlide
    PPApp.ActivePresentation.Slides.Add PPApp.ActivePresentation.Slides.Count + 1, ppLayoutBlank
    PPApp.ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide PPApp.ActivePresentation.Slides.Count
    chr.Select
    ActiveChart.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Size:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
    PPApp.ActiveWindow.View.Paste
    PPApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Align msoAlignCenters, True
    PPApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Align msoAlignMiddles, True
Next chr
PPApp.Visible = True

Dim CurOpenPresentation As Object
Dim PPProgram As Object
Set PPProgram = GetObject(, "PowerPoint.Application")
For Each CurOpenPresentation In PPProgram.Presentations
      CurOpenPresentation.SaveAs path & "\" & CurOpenPresentation.FullName & ".pptx"
      Application.Wait (Now + #12:00:03 AM#) ' Wait 3 seconds to allow the computer time to save the file before it closes it
      CurOpenPresentation.Close
Next CurOpenPresentation


End Sub
```

Comment: Doesn't seem like you need 2 loops here, or `PPProgram` for that matter. Why not just save inside one main loop?

Comment: I think it has to do with the fact that you're closing the presentation after saving it - similar to how you need to loop backwards when deleting rows in Excel. It saves the first PowerPoint, then your `CurOpenPresentation` becomes PowerPoint2, then your loop moves to 3 and you never save 2, 4, 6... etc.

Comment: @dwirony I don't quite understand how this is the case seen as the save and close are within the loop, but removing the line where I close the PowerPoint does indeed fix this problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me further explain the original issue:

Let's say you have 30 open PowerPoint presentations. You start a `For` loop to iterate through all 30. On the first iteration, your `CurOpenPresentation` (the first item in your collection of 30) is PowerPoint1. You save it to a location and close it.

Now you have a collection of **29 open PowerPoint presentations**, and your `CurOpenPresentation` is now PowerPoint2 because PowerPoint1 doesn't exist in the scope anymore since you've closed it. Now you hit the `Next CurOpenPresentation` line and move from PowerPoint2 to PowerPoint3 without ever saving PowerPoint2.

That's why you're only saving 1, 3, 5, etc. :)

Comment: Gotcha. Thank you very much for your help. I would have never spotted that.

Answer (score 2):

You already have `PPApp` as a PowerPoint application object - continue using that and take out the lines defining `PPProgram`.

Also, declare and instantiate an object for the presentation being added:

```
Dim PPPres as Object
Set PPPres = PPApp.Presentations.Add
```

After that, use `PPPres` to work with the presentation

```
PPPres.Slides.Add PPPres.Slides.Count + 1, ppLayoutBlank
PPApp.ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide PPPres.Slides.Count
```

This also means the loop is not needed to save and close the presentation

```
 PPPres.SaveAs path & "\" & PPPres.FullName & ".pptx"
 Application.Wait (Now + #12:00:03 AM#) ' Wait 3 seconds to allow the computer time to save the file before it closes it
 PPPres.Close
```

It's also a good idea to explicitly release these objects before `End Sub`:

```
Set PPPres = Nothing
Set PPApp = Nothing
```

If you want to always use `CreateObject` for each presentation, then the code should also `Quit` the PowerPoint application *before* setting it to Nothing. Alternatively, the code could check for the presence of PowerPoint using `GetObject` and only if it's not running use `CreateObject` to start it. There are plenty of code examples around that show how to do that.